# Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n) = 0$ using the definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I found that the $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left( \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right )=0$. But I have to use the definition of a limit to solve too.

So far I have given $\epsilon>0, |\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}|< \epsilon.$ And now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you format your question in LaTeX?

Comment: I did the formatting for you. Please take a look and use that formatting in your next questions or edits.

Comment: Oten, once you **know** that the limit is $a$, you are not far from showing that the limit is $a$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$.

Comment: I have further edited your title to be meaningful to other users at a glance.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I just don't understand the definition when n is going to infinity.

Comment: An answer has been given that is almost complete. You want to show that given an $\epsilon\gt 0$, after a while the absolute value of our expression is less than $\epsilon$. More precisely, there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$, then our absolute value is less than $\epsilon$. The absolute value is between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$. This is less than $\epsilon$ if $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\lt \epsilon$, or equivalently if $2\sqrt{n}\gt 1/\epsilon$, or equivalently if $n\gt (1/(2\epsilon)^2$. So pick, for example, $N$ $1$ more than the floor function applied to $1/(2\epsilon)^2$.

Comment: Closely related but not a duplicate, because it allows other methods of proof: [Prove that the limit of $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is zero](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582826/prove-limit-equals-0)

Answer (score 3):

Use that $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\leqslant \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: How did the sign change happen? And don't I have to do something with epsilon?

Comment: Which sign change? I just used that $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. For the limit, given any $\varepsilon$, you need to find $N$ such that $|\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n|<\varepsilon$ if $n>N$. If you find $N$ for $1/(2\sqrt n)$ you're done by what's above.

Comment: Where did the less than or equal come in?

Comment: the last inequality is true because the square root function is strictly increasing which means that if $x_1 \leq x_2$, then $\sqrt{x_1} \leq \sqrt{x_2}$. So, we get that $n \leq n+1$ implies $\sqrt{n} \leq \sqrt{n+1}$ implies $2\sqrt{n} \leq \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n}$, then since both sides of the last inequality are greater than or equal to 1, taking reciprocals reverses the order relation