# Prove that the limit of $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is zero

Tags: limits, radicals

How would I go about proving that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=0$? I have tried to use Squeeze theorem but have not been able to come up with bounds that converge to zero. Additionally, I don't think that converting to polar is possible here.

Comment: Hint: Rationalize and it suffices to show that the $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\to\infty$

Comment: Closely related, but not a duplicate  (because the question only allows one solving method): [Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n) = 0$ using the definition of a limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475624/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn1-sqrt-n-0-using-the-definition-o)

Comment: See also: [Show that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\to0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/545704)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

$$ \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}
 = \frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
 < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the last part be $\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}$?

Comment: @cheesyfluff That is not true since $2\sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}$..

Comment: Can you explain how you realized you're supposed to use conjugates? It's not really enlightening otherwise.

Comment: For squeezing, we could use from your results $$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
 < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: @Mehrdad I try conjugates whenever I see differences of the form $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ and that $a-b$ is simple.

Comment: @HenryW: I mean do you try it because you're used to it, or do you try it because you have a reason to believe it might work? Because honestly I don't intuitively understand why it *should* work.

Comment: @Mehrdad To be honest I am used to it. However limits of the form $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ rarely occurs in real circumstances.

Comment: @Henry I see, as I forgot to take into account the fact that the expressions were in the denominators rather than the numerators.

Comment: @Mehrdad, The conjugate of $a-b$ is $a+b$, and multiplying them gives $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2 - b^2$. This is more or less the definition of "the conjugate". In this problem we have square roots, and the conjugate's whole job is to square both terms when you multiply by it, so if we want to do something to get rid of the square roots (at least in one place in the formula) then we want to use the thing whose job it is to do that.

Answer (score 14):

Using conjugate multiplication can be quite useful in cases like that:
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}){\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\over \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}={(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})\over \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}={(n+1)-n\over \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}={1\over \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$.
The last result is pretty easy to work with.

Answer (score 11):

One way is by using the mean value theorem. Specifically, let $f(x) = \sqrt x$. Then, for each $x > 0$, we know that $\displaystyle f(x+1) - f(x) = \frac{f(x+1) - f(x)}{(x+1) - x} = f'(c)$ for some $c$ in the interval $(x, x+1)$. Since $\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac1{2\sqrt x}$ is strictly decreasing we conclude that $0 < \displaystyle \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} < \frac1{2\sqrt x}$.

Answer (score 9):

Note that for positive $n$ we have
$$\sqrt{n}\lt \sqrt{n+1}\lt \sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}.\tag{1}$$
The second inequality in (1) holds because 
$$\left(\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)^2=n+1+\frac{1}{4n}\gt n+1.$$
It follows from (1) that
$$0\lt \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\lt \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}.$$
Now Squeeze.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna attempt to answer in a way that doesn't seem like pulling a rabbit outta the hat, and shows how I *arrived* at a solution.

It suffices to have that $(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n)^2\to 0$, *i.e.*, $2n + 1 - 2\sqrt{n^2 + n}\to 0$. Now, note that $2\sqrt{n^2 + n}$ is large enough to cancel $2n$, but then we also have to take care of the lingering $1$. This motivates us to take a nonnegative function $f$ such that
$$
\sqrt{n^2 + n}\ge n + f(n)\tag{1}
$$
so that $(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n)^2\le 1- 2f(n)$.  Thus it suffices to have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) = 1/2.\tag{2}
$$

We thus find $f$ satisfying (1) and (2):

In view of (2), take $f$ to be the constant function $1/2$. But then, one quickly sees that this makes (1)'s RHS too large to be true. Thus we can try to reduce $f$, but in such a way that (2) still holds. Well, the first obvious thing that came to my mind was this:
$$
f(n) := \frac{1}{2}\, \frac{n}{n + 1}
$$
Now, it's straightforward to check that this indeed satisfies (1).